# Azure Servicebus lock on Delete

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

How can Azure Service Bus Queues can be locked for deleting (accidentally) for user who has Manage rights in shared access policies?

Lock on resource with Lock type "delete" also did not stop deletion.

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

> How can Azure Service Bus Queues can be locked for deleting
> (accidentally) for user who has Manage rights in shared access
> policies?

Do you mean the queue itself still can be deleted after set the delete lock? After setting, the delete lock it seems to make the queue can not be deleted on my side.

[image]

[image]

Or you are talking about the messages in the queue been deleted? (If so, you need to know Azure resource lock can not work on this.)

Comment: I am using a service bus explorer  (https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) and it seems to be ignoring any lock whatsoever.